# Mensagem de fim de execução em um Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Shiny, onde tenho vários `actionButtons` que, ao serem clicados executam outros códigos através da função `source` ou `render` conforme o exemplo a seguir

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(

  #tema
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  navbarPage(title = "exemplo",


             # painél para relatório ---------------------------------------------------
             tabPanel("relatorio",
                      #relatório de movimentaÃ§Ãµes
                      actionButton("teste", "teste"),
                      #relatório de passivo
                      #relatório de passivo
                      actionButton("teste2", "teste2")

  )
)

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  # relatórios --------------------------------------------------------------

  #render relatório de movimentacao
  observeEvent(input$teste, {
    render("endereço do arquivo Rmarkdown no computador",output_file = "teste" ,output_dir = "pasta de saida no computador")
  })

  observeEvent(input$teste2, {
    source("endereço do código em R no computador")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Meu problema é que quando executo os relatórios através do Rmarkdown ou source, os códigos estão sendo executados corretamente, porém não consigo saber quando o código foi concluído para que eu possa utilizar outra função do aplicativo

Gostaria de saber como coloco uma mensagem de conclusão de código e faço o aplicativo shiny encerrar o `actionButton` para que eu possa utilizar outro `actionButton`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar a função `showModal()`, para mostrar um aviso no final da etapa.

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(

  #tema
  theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
  navbarPage(title = "exemplo",


             # painél para relatório ---------------------------------------------------
             tabPanel("relatorio",
                      #relatório de movimentaÃ§Ãµes
                      actionButton("teste", "teste"),
                      #relatório de passivo
                      #relatório de passivo
                      actionButton("teste2", "teste2")

             )
  )

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  # relatórios --------------------------------------------------------------

  #render relatório de movimentacao
  observeEvent(input$teste, {
      x <- 2
      y <- 3
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Aviso",
        paste0("Operação completa. Valor de x é ", x, " e valor de y é ", y),
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$teste2, {
      x <- 4
      y <- 6
    source("Operação completa. Valor de x é ", x, " e valor de y é ", y)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: muito bom, obrigado pelo auxílio